# How to get media URL from cloudinary

Tags: mysql, node.js, cloudinary

I want to upload an image to cloudinary and then get the URL of the image in and store it (the url) in a database but don't have a clue on how to get started. I can upload to cloudinary, but I don't know how to programmatically get the url. I'm working with React and NodeJS. I need help guys

Comment: [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Next time you post a question, please include more context and show examples of what you have tried!

That being said, I would use the cloudinary npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudinary

Uploading will return an object like this:

```
{
  "public_id": "4srvcynxrf5j87niqcx6w",
  "version": 1340625837,
  "signature": "01234567890abcdef01234567890abcdef012345",
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "format": "jpg",
  "resource_type": "image",
  "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1340625837/4srvcynxrf5j87niqcx6w.jpg",
  "secure_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1340625837/4srvcynxrf5j87niqcx6w.jpg"
}
```

So to get the url after uploading, do this:

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;


const url = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cloudinary.uploader.upload("my_picture.jpg", function (error, result) {
        if(result){
            resolve(result.url);
        } else if(error){
            reject(error)
        }
    });
})
```